# change svg fill attribute value using php

Tags: php, dom, svg, attributes

I have been trying to change `fill` attribute of text tag in my svg image.
But it's not working.

**text tag**

```
<text style="font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-size:9.99989986px;font-family:'Times New Roman';-inkscape-font-specification:TimesNewRomanPSMT-Bold;writing-mode:lr-tb;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         transform="matrix(0,1,1,0,27.7761,21.4725)"
         fill="#231f20"
         name="mytitle"
         id="mytitle"
         data-svg="text">
        <tspan
           id="tspan7549"
           sodipodi:role="line"
           y="0"
           x="0">TEST TEXT</tspan>
      </text>
```

**php code**

```
$dom->loadXML($svgString);
foreach($dom->getElementById('mytitle') as $mytitle) {
                        $mytitle->setAttribute('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','fill','#ffffff');

                }
$dom->saveXML()
```

I have no idea why this is not working. i have written a code for image replacement(`$dom->getElementsByTagName('image')`) and it's workin perfectly.

I want to change my fill attribute value using php.Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setAttribute()` only takes two parameters.  The three parameter version is `setAttributeNS()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php
http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattributens.php

However when setting attributes in SVG elements, you don't need to use the namespace.  The following should work:

```
$mytitle->setAttribute('fill','#ffffff');
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you have any idea why getElementById is not working?

Comment: You didn't mention that `getElementById()` was not working. Perhaps you should update your question with that, and any other information you have left out.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue..

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('text');

                    foreach($nodes as $node) {
                        if($node->getAttribute('id')=='mytitle'){$node->setAttribute('fill','#ffffff');}

                }
```